# Targeting app to .NET Framework using Visual Studio 2010 / ClickOnce: Installing for "current user" not "all users"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, clickonce, user-permissions, .net-framework-version

Is there any way to tell the ClickOnce installer that if the targeted framework isn't available on the PC, to install it ONLY FOR THE CURRENT USER, not all users?

The ClickOnce install of the .NET Framework 4 onto certain Windows 7 PCs is failing, and I am pretty sure that's because it's being installed for all users not the current user only, and the current user doesn't have the permission to make changes for all users on the PC. So, we have to visit those PCs and log in as a domain admin and then run the install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework isn't like ClickOnce. It can't be installed "per user" into their profile folders. The framework has to be installed at a machine level and it has to be installed by an administrator.